# Robot Framework: Keword: Expected 2 Argurments got 1

Tags: arguments, robotframework

these error occurs when I add an argument beside ${printSize} which is ${2Hole}.Hope anyone can help me with this

The task still runs and executes everything but error is still there.
I tried adding a separate line for${2Hole} but itis still not working.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCAs4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code within your question instead of an image. Because you are using DataDriver, an example of what's in paperSizeVSPunch.xlsx would also be a good idea to share, although I do not believe it is needed to resolve your issue.

Basically robotcode is looking at your code as if it is a regular task and not one used with DataDriver. So it sees that you are calling the keyword `Print Size VS Punch` (line 39) without the correct number of arguments. I am not clear on why it's only reporting one missing argument instead of two, but the line that error is occurring on should not be needed. In fact, I believe it is disregarded when the tasks are run due to how DataDriver works.

You already specify the keyword to run with `Test Template    Print Size VS Punch` (line 10). You do not need to use the keyword again within the body of the task. Try leaving the task empty (i.e. remove line 39). If you review the first two examples in the [usage section of DataDriver's documentation](https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#usage) you'll see that there are no tests/tasks with anything in the body.

P.S. the body of the `Print Size VS Punch` keyword appears to be incorrectly indented. Lines 17-33 (the body of the keyword) should be at the same indentation level as the line with the `[Arguments]` setting.